# Get the access to SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, hosting

Recently I've got the ssl cert for my domain. Now I want to know how can I get the access to it for data encryption/decryption?

1. I'm using hosting Sprinthost.
2. For this project I have to use JS and NodeJS.
3. CA is Let's Encrypt
4. Type of cert is Wildcard (domain validation)
5. I have access to my web server (Node) through SSH.

I've been searching for answer, but can't find anything about. I'm afraid domain validition and green lock is only options to use it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a let's encrypt certificate, it stays on path:

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/your.registered.domain/your_cert.pem`

I recommend you to use a reverse proxy with Apache or NGINX to point to your NodeJS application =)